# How to delay a loop in android without using thread.sleep?

Tags: java, android, loops, delay

I wanted to delay a for loop without using `Thread.sleep` because that method make my whole application hang. I tried to use `handler` but it doesn't seems to work inside a loop. Can someone please point out the mistake in my code.

```
public void onClick(View v) { 
    if (v == start)
    {   
        for (int a = 0; a<4 ;a++) {

         Handler handler1 = new Handler();
         handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        ImageButton[] all= {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4};
        btn5 = all[random.nextInt(all.length)];
        btn5.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

             @Override
             public void run() {

             }
             }, 1000);
        } 
        }
     }
```

Basically what I wanted to do is that I got 4 `ImageButton` and I change each of their background to red by using a loop in order. Thats why I need a delay inside my loop, if not all the `ImageButton` will just directly turn red without showing which `ImageButton` turn first.

Comment: you don't need a for loop. you can use a Handler itself

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your for loop should be:

```
final ImageButton[] all= {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4};
Handler handler1 = new Handler();
for (int a = 1; a<=all.length ;a++) {
    handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
              ImageButton btn5 = all[random.nextInt(all.length)];
              btn5.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
         }
         }, 1000 * a);
    } 
}
```

This way it achieves your desired behavior of staggering the color change.

Edited for syntax

Comment: It worked but I have another problem. I get an syntax error at the `ImageButton btn5 = all[random.nextInt(all.length)];` when I use your code. It seems like I had to put `final ImageButton[] all= {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4};` for it to work.

Comment: Edited with `final` added to the array.

Comment: this is not working because a is not specific for each runable

Comment: TextView number = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
       
        Handler handler1 = new Handler();
        for (int a = 1; a<=3 ;a++) {
            handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {                    
                    number.setText(String.valueOf(numbersArray[a]));
                }
            }, 1000 * a);
        }

It says, Textview AND a needs to be decalred final! Now, how would i increase if a is final? Any ideas!

Answer (score 17):

You can use a `Handler` instead of for loop. You should not call `Thread.sleep()` on the UI thread.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000L);  // 1 second delay
    }
};
handler.post(runnable);
```

Comment: can you give me an example of using `Handler` instead of loop for my code

Comment: @user3153613 use the above . that ihas 1 second delay and then instead of do something. set the background color to button

Comment: it keeps on going untill you stop the handler by `m_hnbdler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask)`

Comment: @user3153613 how do you initialize your buttons?

Comment: This generates an error that `runnable` may not have been initialized, but you can replace the reference inside `run` with `this`. @Raghunandan I believe you meant `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);`

Comment: After looking this over a little more, I also think you want to call `handler.post(runnable);` rather than `runnable.run();` initially.

Comment: @AbandonedCart corrected it. it was a long time back thanks for correcting.

Comment: @Raghunandan You copied in the **optional** suggestion, but did not address the **error** of attempting to call the variable inside its initialization. I have edited the answer to fix it.

Answer (score 7):

The following code doing the task in every second:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Doing task");
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
handler.post(task);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public void onClick(View v) { 
    if (v == start) {   
        for (int a = 0; a<4 ;a++) {
            Handler handler1 = new Handler();
            handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                ImageButton[] all= {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4};
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    btn5 = all[random.nextInt(all.length)];
                    btn5.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }, 1000);
        } 
    }
}
```

Example for Delay :

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
        buttons[inew][jnew].setBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: just call public void run() inside the loop and make parameters for your button index or button names